# VB Generics "cannot be converted"

Tags: vb.net, generics

For the problem I have these classes:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseLeaf(Of T)
    Implements IBaseLeaf
    // etc

Public Class WebsiteLeaf
    Inherits BaseLeaf(Of Headline)
    // etc

Public Class WebsiteCollection
    Inherits BaseCollection(Of WebsiteLeaf)
    // etc

Public Class SubscriptionList
Private mCollection As BaseCollection(Of IBaseLeaf)

Public Sub LoadSubscriptions(ByVal collection As BaseCollection(Of IBaseLeaf))
    mCollection = collection
End Sub
```

In the Main class I am trying to call the following function:

```
Private Sub FetchSubscriptions(ByVal websites As WebsiteCollection)
        gUser.SubscriptionList.LoadSubscriptions(websites)
        // code
End Sub
```

This will access LoadSubscriptions with passing the "websites" variable.

As you can see LoadSubscriptions expects a BaseCollection(Of IBaseLeaf).

The "websites" variable is a WebsiteCollection, which is a BaseCollection(Of WebsiteLeaf(Of Headline)).

Now I am getting the error: Value of type 'WebsiteCollection' cannot be converted to 'BaseCollection(Of IBaseLeaf)'.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You might like to read about [covariance and contravariance in generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If class `B` is a descendent of class `A` this does not mean that `Collection(Of B)` is a descendant of `Collection(Of A)`!

If you have these definitions

```
Dim stringList As List(Of String)

Public Sub DoSomthingWithList(list As List(Of object))
     list.Add(Date.Now)
End Sub
```

and you could call the method like this

```
DoSomthingWithList(stringList)
```

then the method would try to add a `Date` to the list which is actually a list of strings! Since the parameter is typed as `object` the date would be boxed (i.e. converted to an object) but not converted to string.

Therefore the collections `List(Of X)` and `List(Of Y)` are never compatible, even if `Y` inherits `X`.

---

Let's look at another example

```
Public Class TestClass
    Implements IBaseLeaf      
    // etc
```

What happens if you call `LoadSubscriptions` with a `WebsiteCollection`?

```
Public Sub LoadSubscriptions(ByVal collection As BaseCollection(Of IBaseLeaf))      
    collection.Add(New TestClass())
End Sub
```